# 'List index out of range' error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making code for an inventory which works as when I click x, a space in a list is filled, when I tap z a pos in the list is removed, and when I tap c the list is printed. I know the code is inefficient, but it's just for testing purposes in this stage so ignore how deep it goes into if statements. Anyway, I get an error in my if inv[0] is none line and all those in that section. The error is 'list index out of range' Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
    import pygame, sys
    pygame.init()

    i= 1

    inv = []
    #Code below will add an item to that list.
    w, h = 1000, 600
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
    while True:
            DISPLAYSURF.fill((255, 255, 255))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

This is to fill a position in the list

```
                    if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                            if inv[0] == None:
                                    inv[0] = 'an_item'

                            elif inv[1] == None:
                                    inv[1] = 'an_item'

                            elif inv[2] == None:
                                    inv[2] = 'an_item'

                            elif inv[3] == None:
                                    inv[3] = 'an_item'

                            elif inv[4] == None:
                                    inv[4] = 'an_item'

                            else:
                                    print("No inventory space")
```

This is to empty out a position in the list when a key is pressed. I know it is inefficient, but I don't think it should affect it:

```
                    if event.key == pygame.K_z
                            if inv[4] == none:
                                    if inv[3] == None:
                                            if inv[2] == None:
                                                    if inv[1] == None:
                                                            if inv[0] == None:
                                                                    print('Nothing to drop!')
                                                            else: inv[0] None

                                                    else:
                                                            inv[1] = None
                                            else:
                                                    inv[2] = None
                                    else:
                                            inv[3] = None
                            else:
                                    inv[4] = None
```

This sentence is to print the list, when C is pressed

```
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                            print(inv)
```

Comment: From the code you posted you access the empty list `inv` via `inv[0]`. However post the complete traceback please.

Comment: There are many things wrong in your code. Check for none and replace with None in your code. There is assignment operator "=" missing in your inner most indented else condition. `inv` is just empty list and there is nothing to iterate on so you get indexError.

Comment: @d-coder Oh, good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initialising an empty list without any elements at first. When the event key `K_x` is triggered, the first condition is checked: `if inv[0] == None:` It gets even worse for the key `K_z` because you're out of bounds by 5 elements when you check `if inv[4] == None`.

However, the thing is, there is no 0th element, since your list is empty. What you should do instead, is create a list with 5 `None` elements like this:

```
inv = [None] * 5
```

Another error as pointed out by d-coder in the comments, is that in the second code listing, the statement in the innermost `if` is syntactically incorrect. It should be

```
inv[0] = None
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Didn't try yet but that seems accurate and I'll test it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: It should be `inv = [None] * 5` by the way

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: @TejasK Do note the minor change that Dave spotted.

Comment: This would be much easier with stack operations and checking the len of the inventory before acting on it.

Comment: @J0hn Agree with you there. Not sure if I should introduce those concepts in code to a beginner in the language. But yes, those concepts should be made aware to OP for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, you're doing a stack but not using stack operations for this game.  I showed you stack operations in a previous post.

I gave you the inv.pop() command, to push to the most open spot just use inv.push(whateverIsBeingPushed)

This would cut down on your code greatly.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_x:
    if len(inv) < 4: #inventory isn't full, 4 is max size of inventory.
        inv.push("an_item")                       
    else: #inventory == 4, therefore no space.
        print("No inventory space")
if event.key == pygame.K_z:
    if len(inv) == 0: #length of inventory is 0, meaning no items to drop.
        print("Nothing else to drop, inventory is already empty.")
    else:
        inv.pop() #removes the most recently added item (which is what your code is doing currently)
```